# Postgresql query for filtering a field of type string[]

Tags: database, postgresql

i have table in database called land with a field landType , landType is an array of strings (string[]) i need to write a query that by taking an input for example "N" it returns the row if any of the elements of the array contain the letter "N" , been trying for hours but no luck

prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM "Land" where "constructionType" = "N"`;

Comment: `SELECT * FROM "Land" WHERE 'N'=ANY("constructionType")` try this

Comment: Is the comparison case sensitive or not?

Comment: FYI, there is no `string[]` type, it would be one of the [character types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html).

Comment: `landType` or `constructionType`? Please show the exact table definition (`CREATE TABLE` script) and always your version of Postgres. Is performance an issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have not indicated whether you want the comparison to be case sensistive or not. Assuming case sensitive then:

```
create table str_array(id integer, "landType" varchar[]);

insert into 
   str_array 
values (1, array['New land', 'test']), (2, array['Old land', 'test2']);

select * from str_array where strpos(array_to_string("landType", ','), 'N') > 0;

id |     landType      
----+-------------------
  1 | {"New land",test}
```

`array_to_string` from here [Array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) converts the array elements into a string where each element is separated by `,`. Then `strpos` from here [String functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) searches for and returns the first index for the substring(`"N"`) in the string of elements. If the substring is not found then the index returned would be 0. Therefore the query filters on `> 0` which indicates at least one `"N"` in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just cast the array to `text`:

```
SELECT * FROM "Land" WHERE "landType"::text ~ 'N';
```

Or case-insensitive with `~*`. Won't be fast, which only matters for big tables.